# How to convert this upstart to systemd?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, services, systemd

I used this upstart in ubuntu 14.04 and it worked perfectly fine:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
respawn

script
        cd /media/sf_ACEBot
        exec /usr/bin/mono /media/sf_ACEBot/ACE\ Bot.exe >> /media/sf_ACEBot/log.txt
end script
```

Now I want to have the same thing in ubuntu 16.04 but in systemd. I have written the service below:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/media/sf_ACEBot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /media/sf_ACEBot/ACe\ Bot.exe

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There are two problems:

1. How can I redirect the output? the >> mark does not work.
2. When I start the service, it waits for my exec to stop. I mean I can only press Ctl+C which stops my service.

Please help me to fix my systemd.